# How Can I Stop TNT From Blowing Up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have a Minecraft server, and I want to know how to the ban TNT so it doesn't do exploding damage. I have tried Essentials Protect and BanITEM, and did all the config correct multiple times. I tried all the banning items, but when you place TNT it blows up right when you place it.

Answer (score 1):

To disable mob griefing (basically stop any mob from causing damage to the ground, which includes creepers, the wither, and the ender dragon) type this command in chat:

/gamerule mobGriefing false

For stopping TNT from exploding, it's a little more involved. Basically, you create a hopper loop clock, place any item in one of the hoppers and it should automatically start. Make sure you put a command block on the output (image for the clock is posted here:)

[image: hopper loop clock]

And the last step is to input this command into the command block:

/kill @e[type=PrimedTnt]

And Voila! No more TNT explosions! This command will delete the TNT the second it gets lit, removing it from the game before it gets the chance to explode!

Comment: In recent versions of Minecraft: `/kill @e[type=minecraft:tnt]`